# Passing Model With IEnumerable from View to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to pass a model with an IEnumerable on it from the view to the controller using FormMethod.Post, but when the post method gets called in the controller the models IEnumerable is null. I have been researching different solutions but nothing is working. I know it would be easier to use angular or javascript, but under the circumstances I can't. So my question is there a way to custom bind the IEnumerable?

**index.cshtml** --> View

```
@model MyProject.Web.ViewModels.PeopleData;
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveList", "People", FormMethod.Post))
{  
    @Html.LabelBoxFor(x => x.Country);
    //??? Cant find any binding tools that will work 
    @for(int i = 0 ; i < Model.Names; i++)
    {
         @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Names[i].Valid)
         @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Names[i].Name)
    }
    <input type='submit' value='save'>   
}
```

**PeopleController.cs** --> Controller

```
public ActionResult SaveList (PeopleData model)
{
    // model.Names = null
    // model.Country != null
    DoSomething();
}
```

**PeopleData.cs** --> Model

```
public PeopleData()
{
     public string Country {get; set;}
     public IEnumerable<FullName> Names {get; set;}
}
```

**FullName.cs**

```
public FullName()
{
    public bool Valid {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Basically I want the the view to list all the names with the checkboxes, and if the user clicks the checkbox it sets the bool Valid to true, and if uncheck it sets Valid to false. Then when they click submit I want to send that updated Model to the Controller

Comment: Try `IEnumerable<FullName>` rather than `IEnumerator`

Comment: Tried it and that is still returning empty as well.

Comment: As well as changing to `IEnumerable<FullName>, you also have to change `@for(int i = 0 ; i < Model.Names; i++) {..` to `@for(int i = 0 ; i < Model.Names.Count(); i++) {..` (or `.Count` if using `List<FullName>`) - but using `EditorFor()` as per you own answer is fine (internally its essentially doing the same loop to generate the html)

Answer (score 0):

```
@model MyProject.Web.ViewModels.PeopleData;
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveList", "People", FormMethod.Post))
{  
   @Html.LabelBoxFor(x => x.Country)
   @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Names)

   <input type='submit' value='save'>   
}
```

This fixed it and what is great about the EditorFor is that it creates a checkbox list for you and will automatically update the bool value for you (Valid in this case).

Answer (score 0):

```
       // This is Model
       public PeopleData()
        {
         public string Country {get; set;}
         public List<FullName> Names {get; set;} // use list here.
        }
    // This is View
        @model MyProject.Web.ViewModels.PeopleData;
        @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveList", "People", FormMethod.Post))
        {  
            @Html.LabelBoxFor(x => x.Country);
            @for(int i = 0 ; i < Model.Names.Count(); i++)
            {
                 @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Names[i].Valid)
                 @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Names[i].Name)
                 @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Names[i].Name)
            }
            <input type='submit' value='save'>   
        }
  // This is Post Action Method
       [HttpPost]
       public ActionResult SaveList (PeopleData model)
       {
         // here loop through model.Names to get the names and checkbox values..
       }
```